# Create a matrix with css-grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am studying css-grid through this article: `https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/`

and I am building a simple grid with four columns and three rows.

My goal with this code/exercise is to understand all concepts about this technology. I don't understand why I can't get that by using the below code;

(please see this link: `https://codepen.io/dsfcxv/pen/gOWBqRK`)

What am I do wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you cannot use numbers to name **grid-areas**.

`grid-areas: 1;` is wrong. The right form: `grid-areas: one;`.

here is the link to the code. https://codepen.io/amini-py/pen/RwVevQy

Comment: Thank so must! :) I didn't know I could only use names on this property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas)

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct. You "cannot use numbers to name `grid-areas`". Yes, that's true. (You generally can't use numbers to name anything.) But you CAN use numbers as values in the `grid-area` property. `grid-area: 1` means `grid-row-start: 1`, `grid-area: 2` means `grid-row-start: 2`, and so on.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin I agree with you, but I disagree that you think my answer is not correct. he used numbers in **grid-template-areas`` and it is not correct, but your comment is true in another way and sight.

Comment: I said "not *entirely* correct", because your answer gives the impression that numerical values with the `grid-area` property are invalid. They are not invalid, but they are not applicable in this case.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin I didn't mean he cannot use numbers ever.

Comment: I said "gives the impression". LOL.

Comment: Thanks for your all feedback!